# Invoking a Lambda function every 5 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda

## My problem

I'd like to invoke an AWS Lambda function every 5 seconds, for some monitoring purposes.

According to [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html),

> Rate frequencies of less than one minute are not supported.

## What have I tried

STFW.

## My Question

Can I autonomously invoke an AWS Lambda function every 5 seconds?

Comment: Sorry, but what does STFW stand for ?

Comment: Search the *fine* web. A similar acronym is also popular, as you may imagine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although I can not recommend this way, but if you really need to execute a Lambda function every 5 seconds, you can try this:

1. Create a Lambda function A which is executed every minute.
2. Create a Lambda function B which is triggered every 5 seconds by Lambda function A. (A triggers B, waits 5 seconds, triggers B, waits 5 seconds, ...)
3. Stop Lambda function A after approximately one minute. (You can read the [remaining miliseconds from the context object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) => if you reach >55 seconds, stop execution)

Please carefully consider if you really need this.

Comment: Just use step functions. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/a-serverless-solution-for-invoking-aws-lambda-at-a-sub-minute-frequency/

Answer (score 12):

you can use step functions and lambda for that - look at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/a-serverless-solution-for-invoking-aws-lambda-at-a-sub-minute-frequency/

Comment: This should be the correct answer now (although the cost implications mentioed by the others are still relevant)

Comment: It should be noted a step function will automatically stop (Failed state) after 25k entries in its execution history log.  This can happen real quick for step functions with many states.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/bp-history-limit.html

Answer (score 5):

Thought I'd still answer this.

Your whole problem is that serverless is not a great fit for near constant workloads. They are more designed for quickly scaling in and out. But if that isn't your use-case then you will almost certainly be better off cost wise using an ec2 instance, you can even reserve one. But I do get that you lose the high-availability and some of the other benefits of Lambda, which might want you to still go with this approach.

If you want to use a sledge hammer to make this approach work you could use a StepFunction. StepFunctions can wait in terms of seconds, but the only catch is that they are not suppose to run indefinitely and will die after 1 year, so your StepFunction will need to start another StepFunction before it dies, or you will have to by some other mechanism, i.e. cloud watch alarms.

This approach also costs a bit of money for the number of invocations you are talking about, would ring up a cost of over

> (31,540,000 [seconds/year] / 5 [seconds/invocation] x $0.000025 = $157.7)

Plus your Lambda Costs, (and I think you actually need 2 state transitions so I think you double that figure)

Might be fine if you are only going to run 1. But running lets say 100 would be well over 10k! Most certainly an ec2 instance will cost you less.

Comment: "Your whole problem is that serverless is not a great fit for near constant workloads." I don't think this is true, we use lambda for many constant workloads (eg streaming/transforming log events).

Comment: And that's fine but it isn't the most cost effective architecture for that type of workload.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the full take in serverless with a step function executing every second - forever and a day:

```
service:
  name: your-service

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
  region: eu-west-1
  stage: dev

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modues/**
    - venv/**

provider:
  name: aws
  iamManagedPolicies:
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess
  runtime: python3.7
  versionFunctions: false
  region: ${self:custom.region}
  stage: ${self:custom.stage}
  environment:
    PUSH_FUNCTION: arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-push
functions:

  schedulerStart:
    handler: scheduler.start
    events:
      - schedule: rate(1 minute)
    environment:
      STATEMACHINE_ARN: ${self:resources.Outputs.SchedulerStateMachine.Value}

  scheduler:
    handler: scheduler.handle

  push:
    handler: scheduler.push


stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    everySecond:
      name: SchedulerStateMachine
      definition:
        Comment: "Step Function invoked every minute"
        StartAt: ConfigureCount
        States:
          ConfigureCount:
            Type: Pass
            Result:
              index: 0
              count: 60
            ResultPath: "$.iterator"
            Next: "Iterator"
          Iterator:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-scheduler"
            ResultPath: "$.iterator"
            Next: "IsCountReached"
          IsCountReached:
            Type: Choice
            Choices:
              - Variable: "$.iterator.continue"
                BooleanEquals: true
                Next: "Wait"
            Default: "Done"
          Wait:
            Type: Wait
            Seconds: 1
            Next: "Iterator"
          Done:
            Type: Pass
            End: true

resources:
  Outputs:
    SchedulerStateMachine:
      Description: The ARN of the state machine
      Value:
        Ref: SchedulerStateMachine
```

scheduler.py

```
import os

import boto3

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
step_functions_client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')


def start(event, context):
    step_functions_client.start_execution(stateMachineArn=os.environ['STATEMACHINE_ARN'])
    return {}


def handle(event, context):
    index = event['iterator']['index'] + 1
    lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName=os.environ['PUSH_FUNCTION'],
        InvocationType='Event'
    )
    return {
        'index': index,
        'continue': index < event['iterator']['count'],
        'count': event['iterator']['count']
    }

def push(event, context):
    print("Executed every seconds!")
    return{}
```

Comment: It should be noted a step function will automatically stop (Failed state) after 25k entries in its execution history log.  This can happen real quick for step functions with many states. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/bp-history-limit.html

Comment: Is that applicable here? `o avoid reaching this quota for long-running executions, implement a pattern that uses an AWS Lambda function that can start a new execution of your state machine` -> That's exactly what I do here, restart every minute.

Comment: I have that running now for a year and it never stopped, so it's fair to say that @MarcSmith comment is not applicable here.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that a retry or a slight time drift isn't the end of the world. Another possible method would be to cron an orchestration lambda once a minute that then turns around and creates delayed sqs messages.  You can then use the sqs lambda trigger to invoke your target lambda.

Use the SQS SendMessage DelaySeconds API (it's native likely all of AWS sdk's) as an off set for the number of sub minute calls one wants to make.  For example if you want to make a call every 5 seconds you would create 12 messages

1. `delaySeconds: 00`
2. `delaySeconds: 05`
3. `delaySeconds: 10`
4. `delaySeconds: 15`
5. ...

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html

With this approach one must pay special attention to sqs's lambda invoke and retry logic.  If multiple tries is a problem be sure to setup a DLQ and consider using a FIFO queue.  AWS, by design, may invoke the target lambda more then once.  Note that standard SQS queues are: **at-least-once delivery**, and FIFO queues are: **exactly-once processing**.  It's also possible to have some time drift with this approach as CloudWatch may invoke the orchestration lambda a few seconds "after" the minute.

- https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/

Is this approach better then long running the orchestration lambda, or even a step function?  Eh, that depends on a lot of things.  Personally I find the idea of leaving a lambda running in a wait state wasteful, you have to pay for that lambda doing nothing most of the time, and if it's a large lambda those costs are not trivial.  Using a step function seems like overkill and a much more complex setup then a sqs integration.

At least to me, it seems better to have it spin up, schedule a set of tasks via sqs and die.  This is more complex then a long running lambda, has some concurrency issues one must contend with, but it is all "serverless" if that's where one wants to be.

With all that said, lambda isn't the best fit for everything- if this is a "forever" kind of task consider using ECS/Fargate/EC2, as there is a good chance it's cheaper and ultimately less complex.

Comment: For FIFO queues you cannot set `delaySeconds` per message but for standard queues this works well.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a workaround using CloudWatch Events Rule which would trigger a Step Function every minute. The step function would then trigger a given amount of times an "iterator" Lambda, which will invoke your lambda. Here is the [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/a-serverless-solution-for-invoking-aws-lambda-at-a-sub-minute-frequency/).

Comment: Invoking something every 10 second: ~$18 step function cost + lambda.
once per second: ~$200 + lambda cost. And when that lambda runs for ~400ms it means you get to pay ~$10 for the lambda, and ~$200 for the invocation.
Pretty expensive scheduler

Answer (score 1):

Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute. What you **could** do is write a shell script with an infinite loop that runs your task, and then sleeps for 5 seconds. That way your task would be run more or less every 5 seconds, depending on how long the task itself takes.

But it really does sound like you're doing something that you probably shouldn't be doing though. This feels wrong.

Comment: While it is possible to execute a Lambda every 5 seconds and still remain in the free tier (assuming < 512MB memory and < 1 second execution time), it would have to be the only Lambda that you're using. Otherwise the costs will almost certainly exceed that of a `t2.small` or `t2.micro` instance.

Comment: True, but I won't have to worry about maintaining a machine - security, free disk space, recovering from errors, faulty machines and others. FaaS has its advantages, even when it's a little bit more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever time you invoke your lambda, lets say 1 min. Divide it with 5 secs which u can keep as configurable as lambda gets invoked.

Then let the loop wait and repeat for every 5 secs inside your handler.
This way you will not need any new lambda and lambda call charges.